# Accessing HTML elements with no IDs using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a button that I want to hide in an HTML page, I cannot figure out how to access an element with no ID nor name.

HTML code:

```
<INPUT onclick=getAddress2(event,1) class=Design_btn02 style="IME-MODE: active" type=button value="Address">
```

How can I access the button above?

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0]`, `document.querySelector('input.Design_btn02')`

Comment: Or `document.getElementsByClassName('Design_btn02')[0]`

Comment: The querySelector will only return the first occurrence of `input.Design_btn02`. How can I get all the doms that matching `input.Design_btn02`?

Comment: @ramwin - `querySelectorAll()`.

Comment: Thank you. I think this is more convenient then `document.getElementById`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the element has a class, try the following:

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('Design_btn02')[0].style.visibility= 'hidden';
```

```html
<INPUT onclick=getAddress2(event,1) class=Design_btn02 style="IME-MODE: active" type=button value="Address">
```

Answer (score 2):

Use command `document.getElementsByClassName('Design_btn02')`. It will return a list containing all the doms whose calss is `Design_btn02`.

Answer (score 1):

The element has a class name.So we can access it with the help of class name.`document.getElementsByClassName('Design_btn02')`

The statement `document.getElementsByClassName('Design_btn02')` returns an array of all the elements having class name 'Design_btn02'.